# How to mock specified request use jest?

Tags: jestjs

I want to mock a specified request use jest. For example: in a method, I want to mock like axios.get(uri_1).mockResolvedValue(resp), but I not want mock uri_2 in the same method. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Show us your code. Give a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

[`mockFn.mockResolvedValue(value)`](http://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue) is syntactic sugar for:

```
jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(value));
```

In your case adding a few conditional logic might be enough. You don't even need Jest's mocks.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosGetOriginal = axios.get;

axios.get = (uri) => {
    if (uri === 'uri_1') {
        return Promise.resolve(value);
    }

    // Return original behaviour
    return axiosGetOriginal(uri);
};
```